# MySQL Rows to Columns to HBase (using Sqoop)

Tags: mysql, pivot, hadoop

I have a table that looks like this in MySQL:

```
id | date | num | avg
```

I have found that I can use this for rows to columns and it works so far:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(id, '-', date),
     MAX(IF(`num` = 0, avg, NULL)) num0 
FROM table 
GROUP BY 
    id, 
    date;
```

The problem is I have 4000 'num' values (values are integers from 0 to 4000) and I do not want to write 4000 MAX statements manually. Is there anyway I can put a loop in there somehow? Ideally, I would like to have 4030 columns...

Edit:

I have edited my post to give some more context to the problem I am facing. I am sorry as I should have probably done this earlier.

Context of problem: I have to migrate data from MySQL to HBase. I want to import the values so that each day (which would be represented by a row key along with the id) have many columns (num) which have a value (avg). The column family is avg. I was originally planning on selecting Sqoop's "Select statement" but I understand I may be pushing the boundaries regarding MySQL's columns and I am not sure what the max is. If anyone knows a better way of doing this and can share with me, that would be great.

Comment: Returning 4030 columns of data is not something you should be doing in a SQL statement.

Comment: I need to do this in order to migrate it to HBase with a proper schema utilizing Sqoop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in returning all the values as columns, you need to be try something very adventurous. First look at your query

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(id, '-', date),
    MAX(IF(`num` = 0, avg, NULL)) num0 
FROM table 
GROUP BY 
    id, 
    date;
```

If would be a big mess to get MySQL to execute it as a query by giving MySQL the query with each column formulated.

Perhaps you can get MySQL to concatenate the column values using [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). That function was designed for aggregation (or aggravation if you are the actual developer). You can take all the num values can display it as a column-separated listed of numbers like this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(id, '-', date),
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`num` = 0, avg, 0))) numlist
FROM table 
GROUP BY 
    id, 
    date;
```

You can also change the list to be delimited by pipes instead of commas like this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(id, '-', date),
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`num` = 0, avg, 0)) SEPARATOR '|') numlist
FROM table 
GROUP BY 
    id, 
    date;
```

The [default maximum length of a **GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) is 1024.

You need to change that max length in the session using this:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 10240;
```

before you issue your query.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Yes, I agree...The amount of columns is definitely not optimal for MySQL. I have tried this path (and it worked) but the problem is that I need to store these values into separate columns in HBase when migrating and it seems like Sqoop only migrates the data as stored in MySQL. If there was a way to somehow map the comma delimited data in each cell when storing into separate columns then that would be a great help although I am not sure if Sqoop can do this.